# Trying to login as admin but i'm unable to

Tags: laravel

I created an admin login and I am unable to login.
I have already did the admin table in the database,the guard for the admin and I set up everything on my controller and my model, yet I am unable to login.

this is my controller

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
  // Validate the form data
  $this->validate($request, [
    'email'   => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required|min:6'
  ]);
  // Attempt to log the user in
  if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
    // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
    return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
  }
  // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
  return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use user model? Adding role in user model and making middleware is quite easy for role handling.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @MaheshBhattarai  That's sounds like a good idea but my users table is only for customers that is why I made the admin table so it could be separate

Comment: @OgbonnaVitalis I am not getting an error its just basically telling that my information is incorrect when I try to login

Comment: @Codingisfun22 then post all stuff like guard, model and controller.

Comment: @MaheshBhattarai it wont let me post it keeps telling me its nothing nut code written. you said the other way was to assign roles? How do I really go about that?

Comment: Check answer and if there is any queries feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At First  add column role in your User table
Then you need to make middleware using command

> php artisan make:middleware Admin

This creates a file called Admin.php within the app/Http/Middleware directory that looks like

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
class Admin {

   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {

      if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role==='admin')
      {
        return $next($request);
      }

      return redirect('home');

   }

}
```

You then need to add the Admin Middleware to your app/Http/Kernel.php file

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //
   'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Admin', // this line right here
];
```

Add the Admin Middleware to a route. (Within your routes.php file).

```
Route::get('/admin,function(){

 //statement
})->middleware('auth','admin');
```